# Java Swing & Keybinding - Repainting my cursor

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I have a Jpanel (p), a Jframe (f), and this label (cursorlbl) I want to move around via arrow keys. I have done what I think is sensible in the goLeft() method...but it is not working.

I have a static into called cursx at the top of this class, and the code is in main. Have a JLabel with an ImagIcon in it called cursorlbl - I declared it final so my keybind functions can see it.

Whenever I press the left arrow key, I want the cursorlbl to go away and appear one space over in my TableLayout (from http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout )

Right now, as a big chunk I'll post below shows, I try via this:

```
            p.remove(cursorlbl);
            cursx++; //static var im using to keep track of the cursor
            p.revalidate();
            p.repaint();
            p.add(cursorlbl, Integer.toString(cursx) +" ," + Integer.toString(cursy));
            p.revalidate();
            p.repaint();
```

But this does not seem to be sitting well with my panel. The GUI does not update to the correct location - I'm not sure why.

Here is a chunk of my code that is much larger.

```
    final ImageIcon cursor = new ImageIcon("cursor.gif");
    final JLabel cursorlbl = new JLabel("", cursor, JLabel.CENTER);
    p.add( cursorlbl, Integer.toString(cursx) +" ," + Integer.toString(cursy));
    p.revalidate();
    p.repaint();
    f.setVisible(true);


    Action goRight = new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("right");
            //p.remove(cursorlbl);
            //p.revalidate();
            //p.repaint();


        }
    };
    Action goLeft = new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            cursx++;
            p.remove(cursorlbl);
            p.revalidate();
            p.repaint();
            p.add(cursorlbl, Integer.toString(cursx) +" ," + Integer.toString(cursy));
            p.revalidate();
            p.repaint();

        }
    };


        p.setFocusable(true);
        p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"),
                "pressed right");
        p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"),
                "pressed left");
        p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"),
                "pressed up");
        p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"),
                "pressed down");
        p.getActionMap().put("pressed right", goRight);
        p.getActionMap().put("pressed left", goLeft);
        p.getActionMap().put("pressed up", goUp);
        p.getActionMap().put("pressed down", goDown);
```

Comment: Could we see the tablelayout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm of the opinion that this is a bug in the TableLayout manager.

One workaround is to create a new label to add to your panel every time you want to update (like this):

```
Action goLeft = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        cursx--;
        contentArea.remove(cursorlbl);
        cursorlbl = new JLabel("",cursor, JLabel.CENTER);
        contentArea.add(cursorlbl, Integer.toString(cursx) +" ," + Integer.toString(cursy));
        contentArea.revalidate();
        contentArea.repaint();
    }
};
```

You're able to reuse the `ImageIcon` which saves you a good amount of overhead - but I wouldn't classify it as a permanent solution (because it creates more objects than necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I miss read that and thought you were trying to move your mouse.

There is a class called Robot in the Java API. It has a method called mouseMove(int x, int y). You may want to use that to move the mouse.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: Ah, I think I may have been misleading - "cursor" is the name of my JLabel,  it is a cursor in a different context. For this question I don't want to move the mouse cursor - I want to move my JLabel called cursor.